# Changing puttyTRAY's URL regex in order to match URLs across lines separated by tmux window boundaries

Tags: putty, regex, tmux, hyperlink

I use puttytray to access a shell account on which I have a tmux instance running. Inside tmux, I have irssi running in a window. When people post long URLs in IRC, however, it's annoying since these URLs are broken across lines. Therefore puttytray ends up highlighting something like:

http://blogs.forbes.com/matthewherper/2011/07/13/did-reddit-discover-silent-│

as the URL instead of http://blogs.forbes.com/matthewherper/2011/07/13/did-reddit-discover-silent-censorship-on-google-plus/ .

PuttyTray's regex for URLs is configurable and is currently:

```
(((https?|ftp):\/\/)|www\.)(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|net|org|info|biz|gov|name|edu|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]))(:[0-9]+)?((\/|\?)[^ "]*[^ ,;\.:">)])?
```

Would there be a way to change this in order to match up until the '│' (not pipe) character, ignore the rest of the line, and start matching on the new line?